# HREF inside TEXTAREA?

Tags: html, jstl

im trying to make a hyperklink in a textarea box...is that possible?

This is what i got, just shows up as text:

```
   <c:if test="${action == 'update'}">
<%-- Preserve the indentation for this TEXTAREA in order to keep extra whitespace out of it. --%       >
                 <TEXTAREA class="textarea_readonly" readonly="readonly"  name="mcRemarkOld"  rows="7" cols="100" scrolling="auto">
<c:forEach var="mcbean" items="${form.mcRemarks}">
---${mcbean.auditable.createdBy.firstName} ${mcbean.auditable.createdBy.lastName}, <fmt:formatDate value="${mcbean.auditable.createdDate}" pattern="${date_time_pattern}" />

 ${mcbean.remark} -- <a href="show.view_hotparts_guidelines?remarkId=${mcbean.id}">${mcbean.remark}</a> 

</c:forEach></TEXTAREA><br/>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't. You can't have any kind of markup inside a textarea.

However, since you have marked the textarea as `readonly` I'm going to guess that you are abusing it as a display widget instead of as a tool for getting input from the user. Don't do that.

Use a more appropriate element (paragraph, div, etc), and style it. You probably want to adjust the `font`, `height`, `width` and `overflow`.