# Angular 2: make textarea content with ngModel

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have an Angular 2 form with a textarea field like

```
<div class="textarea-btn-holder form-group form-group-replace">
    <textarea autoGrow class="form-control text-comment" placeholder="Description" 
            name="description" [(ngModel)]="taskDescription" ></textarea>
</div>
```

I'm getting description from Rest API like

```
private taskDescription:string="Some data";
```

In some cases I get URL link as string, for example "https://......."
So what I want is, if the string is hyperlink I want to make it as hyperlink and it should open in a new tab. 
And I want this hyperlink to be displayed inside textarea field only. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Its not possible your question is already asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082991/href-inside-textarea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HREF inside TEXTAREA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082991/href-inside-textarea)

Comment: You're gonna have to sanitize & use innerHTML probably in a div.

Comment: Answer already exist in this question, please search before submit:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39561181/binding-the-value-in-a-textarea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding the value in a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39561181/binding-the-value-in-a-textarea)